# How can I consolidate my errors from the request npm package?

Tags: express, refactoring

So far, I have:

```
request(opts, function(err, response, body) {
  var user;
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
    throw 'Invalid statusCode';
  }
  if (body.status !== 'ok') {
    throw body.error;
  }
  return user = body.user;
});
```

That seems a bit verbose, so is there any way to consolidate this snippet of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really much of an improvement (more like code golf) but here is an example of using short-circuited logical operators for terser Javascript:

```
request(opts, function(err, response, body) {
    err = err || 
        (response.statusCode !== 200 && 'Invalid statusCode') ||
        (body.status !== 'ok' && (body.error || 'not ok'));

    if (err) throw err;

    return body.user;
});
```

An alternative would be to write a wrapper that consolidates the errors for you, if the problem is identical error handling in multiple places:

```
function request_wrapped(opts, callback) {

    request(opts, function(err, response, body) {
        if (!err && response.statusCode !== 200) {
            err = 'Invalid statusCode';
        }
        if (!err && body.status !== 'ok') {
            err = body.error;
        }
        callback(err, response, body);
    });
}
```

Then, you would invoke `request_wrapped` instead of `request` and just check the `err` parameter in your callback, like so:

```
request_wrapped(opts, function(err, response, body) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return body.user;
});
```